# ESQL performance tools

Tags: performance, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I would like to analyze separate ESQL modules for performance on IBM Integration Bus, not whole application with PerfHarness. I know that exists list of good practices for write ESQL (for example, this - [ESQL code tips](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bj28653_.htm))

But is it tool for performance analysis only one ESQL module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check through your Broker 'Web User Interface'. Just turn your flow (with your ESQL code) statistics on and it will show how many time the process took in each node.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is rather old but it still covers the basics. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0406_dunn/0406_dunn.html The section on "Isolate the problem using accounting and statistics" should answer your question. And the part on using trace should help you profile the statements within an ESQL module.

The trace file generated at the debug level shows you how long each statement took to execute down to microsecond precision helping you to find the problematic statement or loop.

To get a trace file do the following

Step :1 - Start a user trace using the command below

```
mqsichangetrace <Node> -u -e <Server> -f  <MessageFlowName> -l debug -r
```

Step :2 - Send a message through the message flow.

Step :3 - Stop the trace using the below MQSI command

```
mqsichangetrace <Node> -u -e <Server> -f "<Message Flow Name>" -l none
```

Step :4 - Read the trace content into a file :

```
mqsireadlog <Node> -u -e <Server> -f -o flowtrace.xml
```

Step :5 - Format the XML trace file into user readable format.

```
mqsiformatlog -i flowtrace.xml -o flowtrace.txt
```

Examine the text file.

Comment: I would note that in ACE the trace files are written in human readable format and so the mqsireadlog and mqsiformatlog commands are no longer necessary.